# Displaying total answer and correct answer of each user

Tags: php, sql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-blade

I have a db structure like this:

Tables:

> users(id, email, password, ...) //default laravel users table
>
> examinees(id, user_id, ...)
>
> exam_quizzes(id, title, explanation)
>
> exam_quiz_answers(id, title, exam_quiz_id, is_correct_ans)
>
> submitted_answers(id, user_id, exam_quiz_id, exam_quiz_answer_id)

I already have the respective models and relationship methods set up.

Models:

```
User, Examinee, ExamQuiz, ExamQuizAnswer, SubmittedAnswer
```

Relationships:

```
// User -> hasOne() -> Examinee
$user->examinee
// ExamQuiz -> hasMany() -> ExamQuizAnswer 
$examQuiz->examQuizAnswers
// SubmittedAnswer -> hasMany() -> ExamQuiz
$submittedAnswer->examQuizzes 
// SubmittedAnswer -> hasMany() -> ExamQuizAnswer
$submittedAnswer->examQuizAnswers 
// User -> hasMany() -> SubmittedAnswer
$user->submittedAnswers
```

In my view, how can I display the **Name**, **Total Answered** and **Total Correct** for every user who is also an examinee, in a table like this:

```
<tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Answered</th>
    <th>Correct</th>
</tr>
@foreach()
{{-- I have no idea what to do here --}}
  <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
  </tr>
@endforeach
```

Comment: what have you tried? What is not working ?.

Comment: I do not know what to try. That is why the argument list in my blade foreach directive is blank. How about some hints so I can try?

Comment: Stackoverflow is for problems not for giving you the solution so you don't have to do it yourself. But a hint : Total Answered . you have got `$user->submittedAndwers` so to get the total you have to count them https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections#method-count

Comment: And for the total correct answers you'll need another function in a model.
I would add it to the user model `submittedCorrectAnswers`

Comment: If all you need is the count it would me better to only return the count instead of all matching records. Functions would be something like `getCorrectAnswerCount` and `getSubmittedAnswerCount` ...

Comment: u want to show only one user info or all of them in one table?

Comment: @SalarBahador all of them

Comment: @Christophvh If I needed the solution only, I wouldn't have described the entire problem in the question, which took a lot of time to compose. But thanks for the hints. Let's see if I can figure out the rest.

Comment: is corect answer is bolean or not?

Comment: Boolean of course :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your controller, u get the users an pass it to view.

```
$users = User:get();
```

and the make a foreach loop to get the answer and correct answers:

```
<tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Answered</th>
    <th>Correct</th>
</tr>
@foreach($users as $user)
  <tr>
      <td>{{$user->name}}</td>
      <td>{{count($user->submittedAnswers()->get())}}</td>
       @php 
        foreach($user->submittedAnswers()->get() as $answer){
         foreach($answer->examQuizAnswers->get() as $quiz){
           $count = $quiz->where('is_correct_answer',1)->count()
        }
      }
     @endphp
      <td>{{$count}}</td>
  </tr>
@endforeach
```

But of course you can write a method in a model to retrieve the correct answers. and just call that method instead.
you can write a method like this in User model:

```
public function get_correct_answers($user_id){

      $user = User::whereId($user_id)->first();
        foreach($user->submittedAnswers()->get() as $answer){
         foreach($answer->examQuizAnswers->get() as $quiz){
           $count = $quiz->where('is_correct_answer',1)->count()
        }
      }
return $count;
}
```

And then in the view u just call that method like this:

```
 <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Answered</th>
        <th>Correct</th>
    </tr>
    @foreach($users as $user)
      <tr>
          <td>{{$user->name}}</td>
          <td>{{count($user->submittedAnswers()->get())}}</td>
          <td>{{$user->get_correct_answers($user->id)}}</td>
      </tr>
    @endforeach
```

Comment: I just noticed I have a wrong relationship between SubmittedAnswer and ExamQuizAnswer and ExamQuiz. Neither of ExamQuizAnswer and ExamQuiz has a submitted_answer_id column in their tables. So a hasMany() relation from SubmittedAnswer is not possible...

Comment: I just changed the relationship from hasMany() to belongsTo().

Comment: @Eisenheim I'm glad I was able to help ;)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Also, how can I sort the result based on the total number of correct answers?

Comment: Never mind. I created a new table for that and stored the corresponding value. I can sort them however I want now :)

Answer (score 1):

Loop your $users and echo the 3 fields you want. Something roughly like this:

```
{{ $user->name }}
{{ $user->submittedAnswers->examQuizAnswers()->where('is_correct_answer', 1)->get()->count() }}
{{ $user->submittedAnswers->examQuizAnswers->count() }}
```

But please don't actually query in view files for the sake of the children.

Eager load related models in your controller:

```
User::with(['submitted_answers', 'submitted_answers.exam_quiz_answers'])->get()
```

Comment: I just noticed I have a wrong relationship between SubmittedAnswer and ExamQuizAnswer and ExamQuiz. Neither of ExamQuizAnswer and ExamQuiz has a submitted_answer_id column in their tables. So a hasMany() relation from SubmittedAnswer is not possible...